# How to specify the domain of cookie with Scala and Play

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, subdomain, session-cookies

I want cookies which is set from `test.domain.com` to be set for `.domain.com` so that that it can still be used from `anothertest.domain.com`. Basically cookies should be shared between subdomains.

I called backend deployed at test.domain.com and set cookies with OK response as follows:

```
Ok("some response").withCookies(Cookie("id", id), Cookie("token", token))
```

And in application.conf I have set the session domain to ".domain.com"-

```
session {
\#Sets the cookie to be sent only over HTTPS.
\#secure = true

\#Sets the cookie to be accessed only by the server.
\#httpOnly = true

\#Sets the max-age field of the cookie to 5 minutes.
\#NOTE: this only sets when the browser will discard the cookie. Play will consider any
\#cookie value with a valid signature to be a valid session forever. To implement a server side session timeout,
\#you need to put a timestamp in the session and check it at regular intervals to possibly expire it.
\#maxAge = 300

\#Sets the domain on the session cookie.
domain = ".domain.com"
}
```

However, the cookie is being set for `test.domain.com` rather than `.domain.com`.
I want to use this cookie with `anothertest.domain.com` .
Can you please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the configuration, you can add all attributes of a cookie when creating it.

```scala
Cookie("bla", bla).withDomain(xxx)
// Or
Cookie("bla", bla, domain = XXX)
```

*(Not sure of exact name, I don't have documentation with me right now)*

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly using 
`Cookie("bla", bla, domain = XXX)`